# template instantiation depth exceeds maximum

Tags: c++, c++11

Haciendo un experimento de recursividad con plantillas, he llegado a esto:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

template< int INDEX = 0 >
void constexpr callInTuple( int index ) {
  if( INDEX == index ) {
    std::cout << INDEX << '\n';
  } else {
    std::cout << "Intentando con " << INDEX << ", fallido\n";
    callInTuple< INDEX + 1 >( index );
  }
}

int main( ) {
  callInTuple( 1 );

  return 0;
}
```

Lo que yo espero, al llamar a la función con el argumento literal `1`, es que se mostrara por pantalla algo tal que así:

> Intentando con 0, fallido
>   1

Pero no compila siquiera, mostrando el error del título:

> template instantiation depth exceeds maximum ...

Si lo intento llamando a la función como

```
callInTuple( 0 );
```

Yo esperaría una salida aún mas breve, tal que así:

> 0

Sin embargo, obtengo **exactamente el mismo error**.

- ¿ Que estoy haciendo mal ?
- ¿ Cómo lo soluciono ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Vamos a jugar a ser el compilador.

---

Las plantillas se instancian en tiempo de compilación cuando substituyen los argumentos recibidos. Hagámoslo: Sabemos que `callInTuple` sin parámetros plantilla se instancia con `0`, así que debemos reemplazar todos los `INDEX` por `0`, por lo tanto la función generada es:

```
void constexpr callInTuple( int index ) {
  if( 0 == index ) {
    std::cout << 0 << '\n';
  } else {
    std::cout << "Intentando con " << 0 << ", fallido\n";
    callInTuple< 0 + 1 >( index );
  }
}
```

El trabajo no ha terminado, hay otra llamada a `callInTuple` con la expresión `0 + 1` que en tiempo de compilación se traduce a `1`, así que debemos reemplazar todos los `INDEX` por `1`, por lo tanto la función generada es:

```
void constexpr callInTuple( int index ) {
  if( 1 == index ) {
    std::cout << 1 << '\n';
  } else {
    std::cout << "Intentando con " << 1 << ", fallido\n";
    callInTuple< 1 + 1 >( index );
  }
}
```

Pero no hemos acabado, ahora se instancia `callInTuple` con la expresión `2`, así que debemos reemplazar todos los `INDEX` por `2`:

```
void constexpr callInTuple( int index ) {
  if( 2 == index ) {
    std::cout << 2 << '\n';
  } else {
    std::cout << "Intentando con " << 2 << ", fallido\n";
    callInTuple< 2 + 1 >( index );
  }
}
```

Cuando haya repetido esto unas sesenta y cinco mil quinientas treinta y cinco veces (este número puede variar según el compilador o los parámetros de compilación: [`-ftemplate-depth`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/C_002b_002b-Dialect-Options.html)) el compilador se dará por vencido.

Esto significa que has hecho la recursión mal: nunca alcanza el [caso base](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursi%C3%B3n_(ciencias_de_computaci%C3%B3n)#Algoritmos_recursivos). Te sale el mismo error porque `index` es una variable en tiempo de ejecución mientras que `INDEX` es conocido en tiempo compilación y el compilador no tiene más remedio que seguir generando instancias de `callInTuple` porque no tiene medios para romper la recursión en tiempo de compilación.

Tus problemas son:

- Si el caso base es siempre menor a la variable de entrada, no deberías estar aumentando el índice si no disminuyéndolo.
- Ambos índices deben ser conocidos en tiempo de compilación: así que ambos deben ser parámetros no-tipo.
- Cuando se da el caso base, debes evitar que se genere la rama que continúa con la recursión: usa `if constexpr`.

#### [Propuesta](https://tio.run/##bU89a8MwEN31Kw53SEpsiKdC/AGBZvDSofXQIYuQ5CCQT8I6h5biv15XdmyaQrfjfdx7TziXXIQYxweNwvRSQa6tp07xtmS/WE/aaPosGSPVOsNJ5aCR4K0@vtbxfFYvz6d3KGAPJbtaLUFY9KQ@XAeCG1Nh3TujtvAIXwxAN3f8djUXt4eLBsCTPByE7QnyfNGEY3PGTRb4AZTx6j9pVCEpJI7STjEQTeDt9cTG0IRGWtozRtnsvmu4ChNI4yWzDK3nQDYwNm1tucZ1yR9rumgD3inqO4R9xoZx/BaN4Rc/JqFmIXa79OkH).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

template< int START, int INDEX = 0 >
void constexpr callInTuple( ) {
  if constexpr ( INDEX == START ) {
    std::cout << INDEX << '\n';
  } else {
    std::cout << "Intentando con " << START << ", fallido\n";
    callInTuple< START - 1, INDEX >( );
  }
}

int main( ) {
  callInTuple< 1 >( );

  return 0;
}
```

Pero esta solución usa el condicional estático de C++17, al estar la pregunta etiquetada como C++11 no puedes usarlo, así que deberías hacer una especialización de la plantilla… pero no se pueden especializar parcialmente funciones plantilla:

```
template< int START, int INDEX = 0 >
void constexpr callInTuple( ) {
  std::cout << "Intentando con " << START << ", fallido\n";
  callInTuple< START - 1, INDEX >( );
}
// ERROOOOOOR!!
template< int START >
void constexpr callInTuple< START, START >( ) {
  std::cout << START << '\n';
}
```

Así que la solución pasará por especializar clases:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

template< int START, int INDEX = 0 >
struct callInTuple { 
  constexpr callInTuple( ) {
    std::cout << "Intentando con " << START << ", fallido\n";
    callInTuple< START - 1, INDEX >( );
  }
};

template< int START >
struct callInTuple< START, START > {
  constexpr callInTuple( ) {
    std::cout << START << '\n';
  }
};

int main( ) {
  callInTuple< 111, 99 >( );

  return 0;
}
```

El código anterior [produce la siguiente salida](https://tio.run/##lU@/a4NAFN7vr/iwQ1qiEKeSaIRCO7h0aB06ZDnOSzg4n6LvoCX4r9eeok0KWbo93vdbNU10UmoY7gwp60qN1NQdt1pWmbj8HBtr@CsTgnXVWMk6hSHGe/H0VoTTmb8@v3xgjw0y4Q2cYihpbU6Fa6zGGQJQNXWsP5v2GrrHA84eBDoudztVO0aaIsiJNbGksh51CMbnlDehIY7ewpT1gYJkUl9ZLsQIcTgXy3zMyOtFn9xccbN2uiycKVPR/6z4Lbw60OqSP6ZW0tCi@hMZx771djtX9mir2bWETSL6YfhWRytP3RD5nL1ar@PHHw):

> ```
> Intentando con 111, fallido
> Intentando con 110, fallido
> Intentando con 109, fallido
> Intentando con 108, fallido
> Intentando con 107, fallido
> Intentando con 106, fallido
> Intentando con 105, fallido
> Intentando con 104, fallido
> Intentando con 103, fallido
> Intentando con 102, fallido
> Intentando con 101, fallido
> Intentando con 100, fallido
> 99
> ```

Comment: Jejeje ... que manía tienes con usar C++17. Para C++11, sin `if constexpr( )`, y la acepto de una vez, que tengo ganas ya :-p

Comment: Qué manía tienes de [vivir en el pasado](https://youtu.be/k80o4hLnfEM).

Comment: No soy yo ... son mis jefes :-(

Comment: Oye, que te la he aceptado pero me he dado cuenta de una cosa ... yo **necesito** pasar un `int index` como argumento de la función (no evaluable en tiempo de compilación). ¿ Puedes adaptar la respuesta ?

Comment: Puedo adaptar la respuesta para decirte que lo que pides no es posible. ¿Te vale?

Comment: ... Bueno ... hay que quitar el `constexpr` y especializar la función mía original para el caso de llegar al límite ... pero se puede. Lo resolví gracias a tu excelente respuesta. Solo por completarla, ya te digo que lo resolví gracias a tí :-)

Comment: Corrijo: especializar la función para el caso de llegar a un límite arbitrario en la recursión (menor que el límite del compilador), yo he usado `50` como límite.

Comment: @Trauma las funciones no se pueden especializar parcialmente; así que no se qué has hecho O_o.